# Tips to solve limits of 2 variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, polar-coordinates

Anyone got a tips on solving this type of limits
$$ \lim_{(x^2 + y^2) \to \infty} \frac{e^{x^2+xy+y^2}-1}{e^{x^2+y^2}-1}$$
I'm always having a trouble finding a good method to solve for limits of 2 variables approaching infinity, usually I'd either use Taylor (mostly if limit approaches 0) or Polar coordinates, but I tried both here without any results, what is the way to think here?

Comment: If we take $y=0$, then the limit is $1$. So we either prove the limit is $1$ or find a different trajectory which yields a different limit, which would imply the limit does not exist.

Comment: @HappyDay: surely not. What would you mean by $(x,y)\to\infty$?

Comment: @AlvinL: but that's not equivalent to $x^2+y^2\to\infty$, which is what OP wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the expression as
$$
\frac{e^{xy}-e^{-x^2-y^2}}{1-e^{-x^2-y^2}}.
$$
The second term in both the numerator and denominator goes to $0$ as $x^2+y^2\to\infty$. But now we can see the problem, which is that the behaviour of the numerator can change widly depending on the signs of $x$ and $y$.

Namely, if you take $y=-x$, for instance, you now have
$$
\frac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-2x^2}}{1-e^{-2x^2}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0.
$$
But if $y=x$, you have
$$
\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-2x^2}}{1-e^{-2x^2}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty.
$$
Another possibility, mentioned in the comments, is to also consider $y=0$, and now the expression is $1$. All in all, the limit cannot exist.